# cpp about for_each usage

Tags: c++, g++

here is my code,I want to read config file using c++
my code is here:

```
//myutils.h

#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

void print(pair<string,string> &p);

void read_login_data(char *login_data,map<string,string> &data_map);
```

here is the myutils.cpp

```
//myutils.cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include "myutils.h"

using namespace std;

void print(pair<string,string> &p)
{
        cout<<p.second<<endl;
}


void read_login_data(char *login_data,map<string,string> &data_map)
{
    ifstream infile;
    string config_line;
    infile.open(login_data);
    if (!infile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "can not open login_data";
        return false;

    }
    stringstream sem;
    sem << infile.rdbuf();
    while(true)
    {
        sem >> config_line;
        while(config_line)
        {
            size_t pos = config_line.find('=');
            if(pos == npos) continue;
            string key = config_line.substr(0,pos);
            string value = config_line.substr(pos+1);
            data_map[key]=value;

        }
    }


}
```

and my test.cpp code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include "myutils.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char login[] = "login.ini";
    map <string,string> data_map;

    read_login_data(login,data_map);
    for_each(data_map.begin(),data_map.end(),print);

    //cout<< data_map["BROKER_ID"]<<endl;

}
```

the config file is:

```
BROKER_ID=66666
INVESTOR_ID=00017001033
```

and when I compile it using :g++ -o test test.cpp myutils.cpp,the output is:

```
young001@server6:~/ctp/ctp_github/trader/src$ g++ -o test test.cpp myutils.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/algorithm:63:0,
                 from test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h: In function ‘_Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct) [with _IIter = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >, _Funct = void (*)(std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >&)]’:
test.cpp:15:48:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:4379:2: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >&’ from expression of type ‘std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >’
```

it seems about reference of pair<>,how to modify to work?

Comment: Well asked question, all the information I could want is there!  If my answer does not fix it I will copy and attempt to compile myself, but I'm almost positive that is the only issue with this code.

Comment: That `while(config_line)` is silly. Re-think your loop conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this line:

```
void print(pair<string,string> &p)
```

should be

```
void print(pair<const string,string> &p)
```

In maps the "key" part of the pair is a constant, and only the second item can be modified.  It is complaining that you are not maintaing this when reading each pair individually in your function declaration, and therefore not guaranteeing that you leave the key portion of the pair untampered with.

EDIT:

Your read looping is kinda wierd.  I think it's okay, but it's bad style.  I think this, or something close to it, will work better for you.

```
while(getline(infile, config_line)) {
    size_t pos = config_line.find('=');
    if(pos != string::npos) {
        string key = config_line.substr(0,pos);
        string value = config_line.substr(pos+1);
        data_map[key]=value;
    } else {
        cout << "BAD INPUT PAIR" << endl; //throw exception?
    }
}
```

The above works with an input file that looks like this

```
blah = bigblah
no equals on this one
```

Comment: when I add const ,it tells:/tmp/ccOKyd69.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `print(std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: So we fixed one problem, no we have another.  Love templated .h files and their compiler output.  Completely criptic.  I will build this on my machine, give me a minute.

Comment: it's my fault,I didn't modify the myutils.cpp.now it compile without no warnings or errors,but it can't print out the map content.

Comment: when I run the program: ./test  ,and nothing print out.

Comment: I don't like your looping for reading in your files.  Are you sure this is working correctly?  I modified it, and placed a version I like better.  But without input files, I can't really help with that.  You can try populating one value in the map outside of your "read" function, to make sure this is in fact the issue.

Comment: Edited one more time, and checked with an input file formatted the way I believe you're formatting them.

Comment: I really make a stupid error. I didn't give the break condition of while(true),so the program is always do while(true) without output,thx ChrisCM.